# How do I determine the arcCenter for a UIBezierPath relative to its parent view?

Tags: swift, uiview, uibezierpath

I am using a CAShapeLayer with UIBezierPath to make a circular progress bar. The code requires a **center** value based on a CGPoint.

```
let circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 100, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
```

I have set the value manually as follows:

```
let center = CGPoint(x: 70, y: 70)
```

However those values are relative to the superView and I need to make it relative to its parent UIView.

All other elements in the UIView are constrained using programmatic UI code like this:

```
sampleText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
sampleText.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: directionsTitle.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
sampleText.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: timerFooter.leadingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
sampleText.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: timerFooter.trailingAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
```

Fixed values may work fine on one device but will be out of alignment on a larger or smaller device. My question is, how do I determine the values for **center** of the UIView that will meet the values required of CGPoint?

I have tried this:

```
let centerX = view.centerXAnchor
let centerY = view.centerYAnchor
        
let center = CGPoint(x: centerX, y: centerY)
```

However, that throws an error: **No exact matches in call to initializer**

The following image reflects where the shape placement is relative to. The blue box indicates the desired UIView area where I want to position the circle.

[image]

Advice from wiser minds would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not 100% following in your description here. When you say superView and parent UIView... are they not the same thing? It's hard to follow with such tiny snippets of code. Can I clarify... Do you have a UIView called something like `CircularProgressView`? And in there you are defining the `CAShapeLayer`? And then you want to place the `CircularProgressView` inside another view (call it `OuterView`)? But you want the centre of the `CAShapeLayer` to align with the centre of the `OuterView`? Please could you show either more code or some screenshot or something? Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the obfuscation. I have added a screenshot showing the desired placement area of the circle. The blue box is a UIView in the storyboard. CGPoint is relative to the entire view and I need to figure out how to place it relative to the UIView.

Comment: No worries. I think I worked out what your issue is here and I would suggest not working with CAShapeLayers like this at all but creating your own custom UIView contains the CAShapeLayer and using that view to position it. That is the standard way of working with CALayers. I've written a brief answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, ok, I think I understand what the problem is that you're facing.

I think your issue is that you're trying to use the `CAShapeLayer` like it is a UIView. When in reality they don't behave like that at all.

What you should be doing is creating a UIView subclass and putting the `CAShapeLayer` in there. Now you only need to worry about how the `CAShapeLayer` fits into its own UIView subclass.

To "position the layer" into some other view you actually don't need to worry about that at all. You just place the new UIView subclass and the layer will go along with it.

e.g.

```
class MyProgressView: UIView {
  let circleLayer: CAShapeLayer

  // add the circleLayer
  // add properties for customising the circle layer
  // Position the circle layer in the centre of the MyProgressView frame
  // I'd suggest using `layoutSubviews` or something for this.
  // etc...
}
```

Now... to position your "CircleLayer" you actually don't need to. You just position the `MyProgressView` where you want it to be and the layer is part of that so will go along for the ride.

From your screenshot it looks like you want the view with the blue rectangle to contain the circleLayer. If that is the case then make the blue rectangle view your custom UIView subclass and ... done. It will now contain the circle view.

RayWenderlich has some good stuff about customising views with CALayer... https://www.raywenderlich.com/10317653-calayer-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started#toc-anchor-002

Comment: I had considered something like this but this solves the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want the midpoint of the UIView's `bounds` I think that's  `yourView.bounds.midX` and `yourView.bounds.midY`

A view's `bounds` is its own coordinate space.  A view's `frame` is its location in its parent space.

`UIView` has methods like `convertPoint:toCoordinateSpace:` and friends for converting points and rects between those spaces.